# how to call a dictionary key that is inside another dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Have a little problem with a simple function that need solving
would like to be able to edit a `dict` with the `update()` but the problem is that I want to update it using its value and not its key
here is my code:

```py
contacts = {"Mohamed": {"name": "Mohamed Sayed", "number": "0123565665", "birthday": "24.11.1990", "address": "Ginnheim 60487"},
            "Ahmed": {"name": "Ahmed Sayed", "number": "0123456789", "birthday": "06.06.1990", "address": "India"}}


def edit_contact():
    user_input = input("Please enter the name of the contact you want to edit: ")
    for k in contacts:
        if user_input == contacts["Mohamed"]["name"]:
            print(contacts)
```

Comment: Iterate over the dict to find the entry with the matching full name, or maintain a second dictionary mapping full name to short name.

Comment: Are you expecting them to enter the outer dictionary key `Mohamed`, or the inner `name` value `Mohamed Sayed`?

Comment: im expecting the user to enter the name it doesnt matter if its the first name only or both names. the most important thing to be able to edit the details of the contact

Comment: But it does matter, because it affects how you find the specific item to update.

Comment: would like to edit it using only the first name then

Answer (score 1):

If they enter the first name, then the sub-dictionary is simply `contacts[name]`.  You don't need to loop over the whole contacts dictionary.

```
def edit_contact():
    name = input("Please enter the first name of the contact you want to edit: ")
    if name in contacts:
        print(contacts[name])
    else:
        print("I could not find that contact")
```

Comment: How could i edit the information of that name then, cuz when i call it to update it doesnt work

Comment: _when i call it to update_ Your question didn't have any code that actually tried to update any values.  Please edit your question to show the code you tried.